# Hide <div> when document.click, show <div> when search box click (php mysql)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a search box which is dynamically populated from a MySQL database. 
When a user types something, it will search the database and using jquery, display the search results with ajax.
Because the search results  has display priority set through z-index, the search results are shown over the top of other form elements.
So what I am doing is when a user clicks on document, the  showing the search results (if any) will be hidden.
Then, when a user goes back to start typing in the search box again, itll show the  again.

The problem I am facing however, is with the last section of my code, where when a user clicks on a p.result item inside the results , it SHOULD take the p.result and put it into the . On click of p.result, nothing is happening. The result isnt being inserted into the input field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */

        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);

            });
               $(".search-box").click(function(e){
                     $(".result").show();
                      e.stopPropagation();
                });
                $(document).click(function(){
                      $(".result").hide();
                });

        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }

    });

$('.result').on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search country..." />
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please note that everything else is working fine. 
Upon removing the following code from the above, it works fine.

```
    $(".search-box").click(function(e){
                 $(".result").show();
                  e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $(document).click(function(){
                  $(".result").hide();
            });
```

.result is the results box div container
.search-box is the div container holding everything.

If anyone has any ideas that could help me clear this up id be very grateful.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the autosuggest from jquery-ui? It seems like your issues would be easier to solve with it since most of the event handling is wrapped up nicely for you.

Comment: Part of your issue is that binding a click handler for the document will capture every single click on the page. So when you click on the searchbox it will close the result, clicking on the search box will make it close, etc. You may wish to check the event target source to see if it's in the result box and skip the hide in favor of the result select event.

Comment: What happens if you run the code without `e.stopPropagation();`?

Comment: `$(".search-box").click(function(e){` and `$(document).click(function(){` exist inside a `keyup` event handler. So for every keyup event you are adding an _additional_ event listener to these elements. Might not be the source of your problem, but it is likely to cause problematic behavior. Performance degradation at the very least